# Assign a plot to a variable

Tags: python, numpy, variables, histogram, figure

How can I save a matplotlib.pyplot as variable/image/numpy.array of a specific size ((1280, 720, 3) or (1280, 720, 1))

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

data = [random.randint(1, 100) for _ in range(100)]
fig = plt.figure()
plt.hist(data)
plt.show()

# Pseudo code below
img = fig.save_as_image(1280, 720, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following trick (using the PIL / pillow library):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import io
from scipy import misc
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

data = [random.randint(1, 100) for _ in range(100)]
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 9))       # Add figsize= to be matched with the dpi
plt.hist(data)

# Trick to write PNG into memory buffer and read it using PIL
with io.BytesIO() as out:
    fig.savefig(out, format="png", dpi=80)  # Add dpi= to match your figsize
    pic = Image.open(out)
    pix = np.array(pic.getdata(), dtype=np.uint8).reshape(pic.size[1], pic.size[0], -1)

pix
```